What is so special about "ve'sechezena" that it is the one word in bold in the whole Amida?
Practically every Siddur I've seen puts it in bold along with the first words of every blessing.
Is there any reason for this?

No idea what you’re talking about. Can you attach a photo of your siddur?

@AlBerko He is referencing the blessing of returning the Shechina to "Tzion" said just before Modim.

@YaacovDeane https://youtu.be/VOmD-xqK2Es

@shmosel Not sure what your link means. Please explain it's relevance.

So far I think Al Berko's response is the simplest one. He wasn't asking which bracha it was, he's asking to see evidence for what the questioner is claiming.

A little evidence that the question is more interesting than I thought: At my son-in-law's suggestion we looked at Machzorim for Yomim Tovim, maariv motzaei Yom Tov, where there is no yaaleh v'yavo. The Artscroll ones at least still bolded vasechezena.

on top of that nothing is boldened in rofe holei, mevorech hashanim, shomea tfila or modim, where you have insertions

I can't formally source it, but I have seen bold indicate where some people have a minhag to say a word out loud with the shatz (or louder than surrounding words). This is common practice at the beginnings of psalms or similar places ("Va-osheiv" before the Song of the Sea, "Et Shem" in Yotzer, etc).  I know I have heard people say "ve'techezena" out loud during the repetition like they do for "Modim", presumably to emphasize our begging for the return to Zion.

Nothing is special about it. Many Siddurim bold or otherwise emphasize the first word in a printed paragraph and many insert paragraph breaks unnecessarily at places where there is sometimes a traditional insertion or a seasonal variant text. Some examples of other common misleading pseudo-paragraph headings where the text is intended to just be continuous when a particular insertion/variant isn't used:

הוד והדר לפניו (notice to pause (the real break is 4 verses earlier after תָּרֵעוּ))
וכרות עמו הברית (variant Mohel-song at a circumcision)
המאיר לארץ (insertion of Yotzer poems)
תתברך צורינו (end of Yotzer poems)
את שם (insertion of a tiny pause)
על הראשונים (variant for Zulat poems)
עזרת אבותינו (insertion of Zulat poems)
וֹתתן לנו (insertion of Havdala on Yom Tov)
ומפני חטאינו (variant text for Musaf)
ותחזינה/ובנה ירושלים (insertion of Yaaleh veYavo)
ועל כולם/ועל הכל (insertion of Al haNissim)
לא לנו/ה' זכרנו/מה אשיב (beginning and end of omitted parts)
מן המצר/אנא ה'/ברוך הבא (beginning and end of responsive part)


Without looking at the introduction to the specific edition of the siddur the OP is citing, your assumption that it means nothing is unfounded. In most siddurim, the publisher and/or compiler mention precisely why they format and layout text in the way they provided in their edition.

Even in the linked examples which you provide in your answer here, all the formatting variations have specific intent and indicate different aspects of all the text elements on the page. Your suggestion that this is meaningless, indicates that you are unaware of the elements of text formatting. For analogy, think of the diacritical marks in the various types of Mesorah. They are not meaningless. Each school has particular intent. So too with text formatting, meaning bolding, or lightening, smaller or larger font size, different font families (like Rashi script in contrast to Ashurit, etc.).

@YaacovDeane "your assumption that it means nothing is unfounded." You seem to be using the word "meaningless" in a way I don't understand. Of course they had a reason, but that reason may have nothing to do with this website. Nothing to do with Torah.

@MichoelR  I addressed the specific significance of the bolded word in the part of the Amidah asked by the OP. Why that word is bolded according to the Sages from Bereshit Rabbah. I also explained the meaning of that particular sentence and blessing as taught by the Vilna Gaon and many others in keeping with traditional Orthodox Judaism. That is exactly what this website is about according to the Tour, and exactly what the OP asked.  It has everything to do with Torah. Meaningless: 1: having no meaning
especially : lacking any significance
2 : having no assigned function in a language system

Here is a source that also claims this is a mistake https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=56478&st=&pgnum=591

Also לא לנו, ה' זכרנו, and מה אשיב in Hallel

@Heshy certainly!

@Heshy The paragraph break at Lo Lanu may also be influenced by Christian bibles having it as the start of a new chapter.

@JoelK or the hagada

The root of the word v’sechezena (ותחזינה עינינו בשובך לציון ברחמים) is chazone (חזון), one of the 10 expressions of prophecy.
The bolding is to emphasize the intent of that specific posuk, that the return of the Shechina to Tzion will be in a way of mercy (רחמים).
That Tzion (ציון) is referring to Moshiach ben Yosef  (יוסף is gematria ציון).
In this context see Rashi and Metzudat David to Isaiah 59:20 who emphasize that Melech HaMoshiach, meaning Moshiach ben David, will be the Redeemer of Tzion.
Prophecies of the חזון (chazone) variety are prophecies pertaining to Judgement and Severity (דין וגבורה) like is expressed in Bereshit Rabbah 44:6.

הָיָה דְּבַר ה' אֶל אַבְרָם בַּמַּחֲזֶה לֵאמֹר (בראשית טו, א), עֲשָׂרָה לְשׁוֹנוֹת נִקְרֵאת, נְבוּאָה, חָזוֹן, הֲטָפָה, דִּבּוּר, אֲמִירָה, צִוּוּי, מַשָּׂא, מָשָׁל, מְלִיצָה, חִידָה. וְאֵיזוֹ הִיא קָשָׁה שֶׁבְּכֻלָּן רַבִּי אֱלִיעֶזֶר אָמַר חָזוֹן, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ישעיה כא, ב): חָזוּת קָשָׁה הֻגַּד לִי. רַבִּי יוֹחָנָן אָמַר דִּבּוּר, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (בראשית מב, ל): דִּבֶּר הָאִישׁ אֲדוֹנֵי הָאָרֶץ אִתָּנוּ קָשׁוֹת. רַבָּנָן אָמְרֵי מַשָּׂא, כְּמַשְׁמָעוֹ, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (תהלים לח, ה): כְּמַשָּׂא כָבֵד יִכְבְּדוּ מִמֶּנִּי. גָּדוֹל כֹּחוֹ שֶׁל אַבְרָם שֶׁנִּדְבַּר עִמּוֹ בְּדִבּוּר וּבֶחָזוֹן, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: הָיָה דְבַר ה' אֶל אַבְרָם בַּמַּחֲזֶה.

This relates to the possibility that Moshiach ben Yosef could have been murdered prior to completing his life's mission.
Jews in every generation have prayed that this will be overturned and that Moshiach ben Yosef would be permitted to live until his mission was accomplished.
According to the teaching of the Vilna Gaon as expressed in the beginning of Sefer Kol HaTor (קול התור, פרק א, ד״ה [א] ״עוד יוסף חי״ וכו׳), already by his generation, those collective prayers by all the Jewish people in all the generations had been accepted by G-d and Moshiach ben Yosef would not be murdered by Armilus, the evil one. That this decree was nullified because of the great length of the final exile, and the afflictions and illnesses which Moshiach ben Yosef will bear together with his total dedication to his lifelong task to complete the Ingathering of the Exiles.
In context of the statement from the Vilna Gaon, it would seem that even though the petition had been accepted by his time so many years ago, it was relying even on the future prayers of Jews that as of his time, had not yet been said. Meaning, that from G-d's perspective, past, present and future are all seen as one.

Is the anonymous downvote about some dispute over the content or sourcing of the answer provided? If there is a suggestion for improvement, please speak up.

Can you source that this is why the word is bolded? Seems pretty farfetched to me.

@DoubleAA Like I emphasized, without reading the actual introduction of the particular edition that the OP is reading, no one can say with certainty. Personally, as a print and typography professional with almost 40 years experience, including in Hebrew layout, all the unusual elements within text are not random. Professional formatting is always done with intention. If they bolded that particular word in each blessing, it is for emphasis. What I wrote is explaining that words emphasis for that blessing according to Orthodox tradition.

None of this seems to have anything to do with why that word is bolded. There are a lot of important statements by Chazal about the word "Chazon" (as indeed for any word in the holy tongue), but it does not address this question unless you have a source. No matter which word was bolded, you could have written a similar answer.

This seems like a bunch of arbitrary connections. Justifications, not reasons. Extremely בדיעבד. Plus, it doesn’t apply to non-Ashkenazic נוסחים.

@Qwertrl The plural of נוסח is נוסחות. The first text quoted in the answer is Midrash Rabbah which is considered authoritative by both Ashkenazim and Sephardim. Based on the quality of your comments, your critique and opinion are of little value.

@YaacovDeane In other words, you’re going to ignore my comment not because of its merit, but because you don’t respect me or my opinions? Even if I were spouting absolute nonsense, the correct thing to do is disprove my comment on a logical basis. Jews never engage in ad hominem attacks.

@YaacovDeane My statement regarding this answer’s limited applicability is because, for it to make any sense at all, the bolded word must be ותחזינה, which is only the case in Ashkenazic Siddurim. It’s not about the Midrash itself.

@YaacovDeane (PS—the plural of נוסח is indeed נוסחים)
